# CoreLocation Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake", referenced from:
      -[ViewController loadView] in ViewController.o
```

I looked at previous StackOverflow posts and they said to make sure the CoreLocation.framework was in "Link Binary with Libraries" in the build phases tab in the target, which I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1 )

Make certain your target membership is checked *on* for CoreLocation.framework, like this:

[image: target membership checked on]

2 )

Make certain that you have done an "`#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`" at the top of your ViewController.m file.